# Does the pre-ejaculate of man contain sperm?

Tags: sex

[BeforePlay](http://beforeplay.org) writes in [8 Pregnancy Prevention Myths: Busted](http://beforeplay.org/2013/06/8-pregnancy-prevention-myths-busted/):

> there’s also pre-ejaculate to worry about, which does indeed contain sperm and can lead to pregnancy

[KinseyConfidential](http://kinseyconfidential.org) writes in [Q&A: Can You Get Pregnant From Pre-Cum?](http://kinseyconfidential.org/can-you-get-pregnant-from-pre-cum/) :

> Sexuality and health educators often warn individuals that pre-ejaculate might have sperm in it and thus could cause a pregnancy.
>
> Theoretically this is true, as there might be sperm that are still “left over” in the urethra from a previous ejaculation earlier that day or earlier in that same sexual session (either because of masturbation or sexual activity with a partner). Thus if sperm are “left over” in the urethra and then a man’s Cowper’s glands release pre-ejaculatory fluid, and it comes forth to the tip of the penis during arousal, then there is a chance that some sperm could be carried in this fluid and get into his partner’s body, if they are having intercourse without a condom.

Is the description that sperm doesn't contain naturally in pre-cum but can only be contained in it when there was recent ejakulation accurate or is it also contained naturally?

Answer (score 4):

Sperm does not naturally exist in pre-cum since sperm is released at the point of ejaculation.  However, both the articles you site are correct in that preexisting sperm already in the urethra could travel out with the pre-cum.

A quote from Teen Clinic on [pre-ejaculate](http://teenclinic.org/about/get-answers/ask-us/if-my-boyfriend-and-i-had-unprotected-sex-but-he-pulled-out-far-before-he-could-ejaculate-can-you-still-get-pregnant-i-have-used-a-period-tracker-and-it-says-im-not-fertile-but-i-am-still-stressin/)

> Although pre-ejaculate does not contain sperm when it is produced, it can pick up leftover sperm in the urethra. This means that pre-ejaculate can contain sperm when it leaves the body, creating a risk for pregnancy.

[AmericanPregnancy.org](http://americanpregnancy.org/getting-pregnant/can-you-get-pregnant-with-precum/) also mentions this same thing.

One hygiene tip I've heard to help with this is for the man to urinate after sex to help clean out the urethra of both sperm and as a preventative measure against STDs.

Core Physicians also mentions that

> You can help prevent UTIs if you: Urinate soon after sex.

Comment: Why do you believe what you believe? Where's your evidence?

Comment: Please note that this site (unlike many on SE) requires [sources which support answers](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/283/) . Please see the [site tour](http://health.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help sections](http://health.stackexchange.com/help) for more information about Health.SE.

Comment: Thank you for notifying me, I will add at least 1 supporting source.

Comment: I didn't have enough points to add the link for [Core Physicians](http://www.corephysicians.org/news-and-health-library/health-library/urinary-system/urin5365/) so I'm adding that here.  Hopefully, either someone else or I can edit it into my answer later.

Comment: This UN site says that urination post sex does not decrease the risk for STDs. http://www.un.org/popin/popis/journals/network/network163/astd163.html

Answer (score -1):

Pre-ejaculate or precum is a pre-fluid that a guy releases during the intercourse. This fluid is also popular with name pre- seminal fluid.

This fluid **contains spermatozoa but not so much**. But this spermatozoa is enough to make a girl or woman pregnant. Girls with high fertility rate can get [pregnant from precum](https://thelifesquare.com/pregnant-from-precum-8575481/).

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). It is great that you included a reference in your answer, but there are more reliable sources. You can have a look at [this meta post](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources) to get some ideas where to find them. Thanks!